# How to delete class object in python

Tags: python

TypeError: 'employee' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I AM GETTING THIS TYPE OF ERROR

```
name = input("Enter name you want to delete : ")
    for i in lst:
        if name in i.name:
            lst.pop(i)
            print("Employee deleted!")
```

I was expecting that the object would get deleted But it Showing type error
TypeError: 'employee' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: `list.pop` accepts an index, not an object to delete. If you want to pass an actual object, use `list.remove`. Also, don't remove items from the list while iterating through it.

Comment: is 'lst' a list of class objects ?

Comment: We don't even know what `lst` is. You should post a [mre]. Anyway, did you check about [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) before using it? The argument is expected to be the ***index*** of the object to delete, not the object

Answer (score 0):

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) the method `list.pop` except an integer as parameter with give the position of the element to remove in the list.

From your code, the list `lst` seems to contain objects of the `employee` class and this isn't an integer. For your case, the `list.remove` function will be the one to use since it work with the objects inside the list rather than the position in it.
You should also implement the [__eq__](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__eq__/) method in your `employee` class if it's not already done, this is what python will use to compare the employee object in your list and the one to delete.

A last point, if you really want to use the `list.pop` method instead of `list.remove` you can do it by using `list.index` first to get the position of the object to remove from the list.

```
lst.pop(lst.index(i))
```

Comment: That is not a good suggestion as removing items while iterating on the list will create unwanted side-effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207427/6045800)